# Using String Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I tried to store strings in an array. But there is a mistake. My code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>

const long long max_size = 2000;         // max length of strings
const long long N = 40;                  // number of closest words that will be shown
const long long max_w = 50;              // max length of vocabulary entries

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *f;
  char st1[max_size];
  char kelimeler[max_size];     
  char *kelimelerim[max_size];  //string array initialization here
  char *bestw[N];
  char file_name[max_size], st[100][max_size];
  float dist, len, bestd[N], vec[max_size];
  long long words, size, a, b, c, d, cn, bi[100];
  char ch;
  float *M;
  char *vocab;

  strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
  f = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Input file not found\n");
    return -1;
  }


  fscanf(f, "%lld", &words);
  fscanf(f, "%lld", &size);
  vocab = (char *)malloc((long long)words * max_w * sizeof(char));
  for (a = 0; a < N; a++) bestw[a] = (char *)malloc(max_size * sizeof(char));
  M = (float *)malloc((long long)words * (long long)size * sizeof(float));
  if (M == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot allocate memory");
    return -1;
  }

  for (b = 0; b < words; b++) {
    a = 0;
    int sayac=0;
    while (1) {
      sayac++;  
      vocab[b * max_w + a] = fgetc(f);
      if (feof(f) || (vocab[b * max_w + a] == ' ')) {

        strcpy(kelimeler,&vocab[b * max_w + a-sayac+2]);  //gets the string here
        kelimelerim[b] = kelimeler;                      //and store it into string array here
        printf("%s %lld\n",kelimelerim[b],b); 
        sayac=0;
        break;

      }
      if ((a < max_w) && (vocab[b * max_w + a] != '\n')) 
        a++;
    }
    vocab[b * max_w + a] = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < size; a++) 
    fread(&M[a + b * size], sizeof(float), 1, f);
    len = 0;
    for (a = 0; a < size; a++) 
    len += M[a + b * size] * M[a + b * size];
    len = sqrt(len);
    for (a = 0; a < size; a++) 
    M[a + b * size] /= len;
  }
  fclose(f);

  int index;
  for (index = 0; index < words; index ++){
      printf("%s %d \n",kelimelerim[index ], index );
  }
  // here, the loop prints last string stored into array, for all indexes.
```

I deleted the unimportant rows. When I run the above code and print the kelimelerim array, the last string is printed for all indexes of the array. Where is my mistake? Could you help me, please.

Comment: I dont get runtime error. As I said, I delete unrelated rows of the code. I have conflict with array of strings only.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? For instance, `f` is not declared..

Comment: Post the complete code to avoid confusion.

Comment: You might also like to show us how you print the array.

Comment: I post the full code now. Thanks for your interests..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
kelimelerim[b] = kelimeler;
```

does not copy any data, but only stores the address of `kelimeler` to `kelimelerim[b]`.  If then looping over `kelimelerim[b]`'s elements, only references to `kelimeler` are found and as `kelimeler` gets re-used for each iteration, it contains the string read last, which then in turn is printed for each of element of `kelimelerim[b]`.

---

**Update**:

To fix this either replace `kelimelerim[b]` by an array of "string" not just pointers to strings  and do

```
strcpy(kelimelerim[b], kelimeler);
```

or dynamically create a real copy of `kelimeler` by doing:

```
kelimelerim[b] = strdup(kelimeler);
```

Be aware that for this latter case each call to `strdup()` allocates memory from the heap, which you shall free if not used anymore, by calling `free()` on each elelment of `kelimelerim`.

Also `strdup()` isn't Standard C but a POSIX extension. You might need to `#define` something to have it avaliable. See your implementation's documentaion on `strdup()` for details.

---

If `strdup()` is not available you might like to use this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include <string.h> /* for strcpy() */
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */

char * strdup(const char * s)
{
  char * p = NULL;

  if (NULL == s)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    p = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);
    if (NULL == p)
    {
      errno = ENOMEM;
    }
    else
    {
      strcpy(p, s);
    }
  }

  return p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `vocab`, so the following has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
  vocab[b * max_w + a] = fgetc(f);
```

From that point on, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `char *vocab;` as uninitialized pointer. This results in undefined behavior. You have to initialize this pointer before using it with a valid memory ( e.g. using `malloc`).